# Hide body scroll bars from user while still allowing the page to move with jQuery scrollTo

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow, scrollto

Sounds like a UX no-no.. but go with it.

I'm using jQuery scrollTo to move the page around to absolutely positioned div sections. I'd like to remove the scrollbars so that the user can't move from section to section without using the navigation (which is always present).

Possible? `overflow:hidden;` was my first thought, but it doesn't even work theoretically.

Thanks all!

Comment: When you used `overflow:hidden`, did you set a height for the container?

Comment: Yeah, used it on the body tag whose width and height are set to 1000% (three zeros).

Comment: Oops, here's where the overflow:hidden; theory gets wonky- the divs are absolutely positioned, so hiding the body's overflow doesn't matter. they're not in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it.

```
html{overflow:hidden;}
```

*'cause they're not in the body!*